# Laravel Query Pivot Table with 3 Relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I would appreciate in advance the help you could give me about the next problem that I can't solve.

I have 3 Tables

```
Contracts
Currencies
Amounts
```

and a Pivot Table

```
contract_currency_amount
```

Here I show you the migrations

**Contracts**

```
<?php

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateContractsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Contracts Table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $table = 'contracts';

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create($this->table, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('number')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists($this->table);
    }
}
```

**Currencies**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCurrenciesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('currencies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('abbreviation');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->boolean('active')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('currencies');
    }
}
```

**Amounts**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAmountsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Amounts Table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $table = 'amounts';

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create($this->table, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->float('amount');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists($this->table);
    }
}
```

**Contract_Currency_Amount Pivot Table**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateContractCurrencyAmountTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Pivot Table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $table = 'contract_currency_amount';

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create($this->table, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('contract_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('currency_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('amount_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('contract_id')
                ->references('id')->on('contracts')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('currency_id')
                ->references('id')->on('currencies')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('amount_id')
                ->references('id')->on('amounts')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists($this->table);
    }
}
```

I have created the models for each of those tables, including a model for the pivot table, but I don't know how to make a query to the pivot table so that it returns all the data of a specific record, relating the 3 tables. for example I want in a view with Blade to go through a variable to show all the amounts, of a specific contract, and to be able to go through that variable in the following way:

```
@foreach($amounts as $amount)
    {{ $amount->currency->abbreviation }}
@endforeach
```

I mean, I want the query to return the related values ​​of the 3 tables. I have no experience in the use of pivot tables, I would appreciate any help ..

**EDIT 1**

**Amount Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Amount extends Model
{
    /**
     * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['amount'];
}
```

**Currency Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Currency
 *
 * @property $id
 * @property $abbreviation
 * @property $description
 * @property $active
 * @property $created_at
 * @property $updated_at
 *
 * @package App
 * @mixin \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
class Currency extends Model
{
    /**
     * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['abbreviation','description','active'];
}
```

**Contract model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Entity;
use App\Models\CInitiative;

class Contract extends Model
{
    // TODO: This!
}
```

**ContractCurrencyAmount Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class ContractCurrencyAmount extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'contract_currency_amount';
}
```

Comment: please put your all model code.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do here but from what I can see, I don't think you need a 3 way pivot table here... You won't be able to do `$amount->currency->abbreviation`, because you database design is stating that an amount can have multiple currencies, in this case you would have to loop through `$amount->currencies` in order to get abbreviation.

Comment: @VikasKatariya See EDIT 1. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertKujawa Hello, thank you very much for your interest in my question. So what do you think would be the solution for it? Basically, what I need is to go through the contract_currency_ammount pivot table and get all the records with their relationships from a given contract.

Comment: I just don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve here, I understand that you have many contacts that can have multiple currencies, but I don't understand the amount model. Is it the contract total for the chosen currency?

Comment: @RobertKujawa Oh! .. I understand you, okay, I explain what is the relationship I am trying to achieve. A contract can have several amounts, and each amount can be defined in different currencies (ex: USD, EUR, etc).

Comment: Ok, so can a contract have multiple amounts for a single currency? for example: contract1 has amount = 100 and currency = USD. contract1 also has amount = 200 and currency = USD? If yes than you do need a 3 way pivot table if the answer is no, than you only need a pivot between contract and currency.

Comment: @RobertKujawa exactly, as you mentioned in the first case, a contract can have different amounts in different currencies and these can be repeated.

Comment: I added an answer bellow, it should help you go in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you are looking for you must setup your models correctly. You must setup you ContractCurrencyAmount Model to be a normal eloquent model instead of extending pivot.

**ContractCurrencyAmount**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ContractCurrencyAmount extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contract_currency_amount';

    public function contract()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Contract');
    }

    public function currency()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Currency');
    }

    public function amount()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Amount');
    }
}
```

**Contract**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contract extends Model
{
    public function relations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ContractCurrencyAmount', 'contract_id');
    }
}
```

**Currency**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Currency extends Model
{
    public function relations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ContractCurrencyAmount', 'currency_id');
    }
}
```

**Amount**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Currency extends Model
{
    public function relations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ContractCurrencyAmount', 'amount_id');
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
foreach($amounts as $amount) {
{
    foreach($amount->relations as $relation) {
        $relation->currency->abbreviation;
    }
}
```

You can also make use of eager loading to optimize your database queries:

```
$amounts = Amount::with('relations.currency')->get();
```

This will preload all the data you need in the for loops above, instead of querying the database on each iteration.

Comment: A while ago you asked me a question that made me reflect. And I think it would be more convenient to use the second case you told me about, where a contract has several amounts and each amount can only have one currency and only 1. I would appreciate it if you could help me implement this type of situation. make a relationship between contract-currency, it would not be more convenient to make the relationship between contract amount? Could you help with this?

Comment: Today when you go to sleep and think about how good you did in the day ... keep in mind that you saved my day. Thank you

Comment: @LeonardoYanes, No problem! That's what StackOverflow is all about. If you would like for me to help you the other way, just make another question pointing out those details, you can link it in the comments. But as a short answer you would create a pivot table called `contract_currency` and the foreign keys to the two tables plus an additional `$table->double('amount');` column and when you retrieve your relationships you would do something like this in your Contract model to retrieve currencies: `$this->belongsToMany('App\Currency')->withPivot('amount');`